# Is closing a modal view a type of segue? Can I use prepareForSegue function? Swift/xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I´m making an app in Xcode V6 and I´m trying to send a variable to the main viewController when i close my modal view which appeared after I press a button on the main viewController.
I open my app and see storyboard1 with a button1, I click button1 and a storyboard2 appears in modal view. When I close the modal view I want to send a variable created in storyboard2 to storyboard1. It´s the sending I have problems with.
I have this code:
Storyboard2:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var sendValues = "This is a title!"

    let destinationValues = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
    destinationValues.recieveString = sendValues     
}
```

Storyboard1

```
var recieveString: String = ""
println(recieveString)
```

I try to print it when I press a button but nothing happens..
when I segue between the views I try to print it but nothing is printed, It´s like the segue did´t work...
Any ideas?

Comment: It's not a type of segue.  But even if it were, it looks like the code you're doing in "Storyboard1" would just always print an empty string no matter what.

Comment: I assume you mean controller 1 and controller 2, not storyboard1 and storyboard2  (a storyboard is a file-- do you have more than one .storyboard file?). You can use an unwind segue to go back if you want. That will allow you to use prepareForSegue.

Comment: Yes I mean controller 1 and 2, rdelmar. And yes, nhgrif, right now it just prints out an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern often used in iOS development for this kind of case is delegation. Basically you pass your original (presenter) view controller as an object that conforms to a protocol defined by the presented view controller. Then from the presented view controller you can modify the presenter's variables.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into how to use delegation